# Autoadjust content of UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have already determined the bounds of `UILabel`. Single line, 2-3 words. I have to change the font size. What is the best solution to adjust the content into strongly determined rectangle programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to check the sizes manually. The other solutions are working improperly. May be this code will help to somebody. Here the code to solve:

```
-(void) autoResizeLabel: (UILabel*) label withMaxWidth:(CGFloat)mw withMaxHeight:(CGFloat)mh
{

    CGFloat fontSize = 1.f;

    CGFloat outSize = fontSize;
    CGFloat mDelta = 30.f;
    CGFloat delta = 1.f;
    BOOL activated = NO;
    BOOL broken = NO;
      for (float fSize = fontSize; fSize < fontSize + mDelta; fSize += delta)
    {
        CGRect r = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:label.frame.size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fSize]} context:nil];
        CGFloat width = r.size.width;
        CGFloat height = r.size.height;


        if (mw <= width || mh <= height)
        {
            if (activated)
            {
                outSize = fSize - delta;
            }
            broken = YES;
           break;
        }
        activated = YES;

        //NSLog(@"%f;%f;%f",fSize,mw,mh);
    }
    if (activated && !broken) outSize = fontSize + mDelta - delta;
    [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:outSize]];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the minimum font scale of the label

```
_myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
_myLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5f;
```

Comment: It does if you set `_myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;`

Comment: Ok, here's the process - you call the `[label sizeToFit];`, it fits your content in accordance with the current font of the label. You then change the font and here's where the minimum scale factor will kick in.

Answer (score 0):

Use Autoshrink property in your XIB (or programmatically) and set minimum Font Size and your text will be adapted to the space. But with a minimum font.

[image]